# Osgi DOTS error with HTTP task

Tags: lotus-domino, tasklet

Osgi DOTS error with HTTP task

I have strange behavior with these tasks.
If the http task is running, error is displayed ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

```
> load dots
- Domino OSGi Tasklet Container is alreadyrunning with this profile: Message Queue name already in use.

> tell dots taskinfo UpdateWidgetsTask
- HTTP JVM: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: -1
- HTTP JVM:        at org.openntf.domino.extmgr.events.EMEventIds.getEMEventFromId(EMEventIds.java:38)
- HTTP JVM:        at org.openntf.domino.extmgr.EMBridgeMessageQueue$QueueDispatcher.run(EMBridgeMessageQueue.java:54)
- HTTP JVM:        at org.openntf.domino.thread.AbstractWrappedTask.invokeWrappedTask(AbstractWrappedTask.java:217)
- HTTP JVM:        at org.openntf.domino.thread.AbstractWrappedTask.callOrRun(AbstractWrappedTask.java:196)
- HTTP JVM:        at org.openntf.domino.thread.DominoExecutor$DominoWrappedRunnable.run(DominoExecutor.java:58)
- HTTP JVM:        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:450)
- HTTP JVM:        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:314)
- HTTP JVM:        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:149)
- HTTP JVM:        at org.openntf.domino.thread.AbstractDominoExecutor$DominoFutureTask.run(AbstractDominoExecutor.java:235)
- HTTP JVM:        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
- HTTP JVM:        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
- HTTP JVM:        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:583)
- HTTP JVM:        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:384)
- HTTP JVM:        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:580)
- HTTP JVM:        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:767)
- Admin Process: Searching Administration Requests database
```

If we stop http, it looks like Dots works correctly.

```
> tell http q
- Domino Off-Line Services HTTP extension unloaded.
- XSP Command Manager terminated
- HTTP JVM: websocket server stopped.
- HTTP Server: Shutdown

> tell dots taskinfo UpdateWidgetsTask
- [DOTS]
- [DOTS] ID: UpdateWidgetsTask
- [DOTS] Description: null
- [DOTS] Run on start: false
```

I have tried with http, but without websocket and the result is the same.It is also indifferent, in what order the http task is started, it always kills dots.

I do not understand why this happens ... on another identical server and with the same configuration this error does not happen.

Any help is appreciated,

regards

Comment: It's an exception in OpenNTF Domino API (ODA). Have you tried without loading ODA? Have you tried with the latest version of ODA (currently 3.2)?

Comment: Hi Henrik and thanks for the quick and accurate answer:

I had ODA 3.1.0 and I changed it to 3.2.0 and everything works perfectly.

Thank you very much, I was already despairing ...

regards

Comment: Great to hear. I've added my comment as an answer so that you can accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an exception in OpenNTF Domino API (ODA). Have you tried without loading ODA? Have you tried with the latest version of ODA (currently 3.2)?

Comment: Yes, I have done this second test and no errors appear. Then I understand that I did not need it and that the API version 3.1.0 was the one that was causing me the error.

Thank you very much